# Menu ajax y redirección

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un menu con ajax el cual me pone las paginas dentro de un div y uso el siguiente script

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#menu a").click(function(){
         var url=$(this).attr("href");
         $("#contenido").load(url);
         return false;
      });       
   }); 
</script>
```

Las paginas que se cargan dentro del div con `id="contenido"` a su vez pueden contener enlaces o formularios q me redireccionan a otras paginas, al hacer esas redirecciones como las tengo actualmente me pone dichas paginas en una pagina a parte, fuera del div contenido.

¿Cómo hago para que la redireccion se haga a su vez en el div  con id="contenido"?